# PowerBI Embedded V2 Direct Query - Azure Sql credentials not updated programatically

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I'm programatically creating a workspace and importing a Direct-Query report into PowerBI Embedded V2. Everything works fine except the report data source credentials which are not updated.

This is the code for the import flow:

```
await _powerBIService.ImportPbixAsync(newWorkspaceId, reportNameWithoutExtension, fileStream);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Imported report {0} for {1} ({2})", reportNameWithoutExtension, persona.Name, persona.Id);

                                    string datasetId = null;
                                    while (datasetId == null)
                                    {
                                        //get DataSource Id                
                                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                                        datasetId = await _powerBIService.GetDatasetIdFromWorkspace(newWorkspaceId, reportNameWithoutExtension);
                                    }                                       

                                    //update the connection details
                                    await _powerBIService.UpdateConnectionAsync(newWorkspaceId, datasetId, persona.SQLUser, persona.SQLPassword);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Updated connection details for dataset {0}", reportNameWithoutExtension);

                                    // get gateway ID
                                    var gatewayId = await _powerBIService.GetGatewayIdFromWorkspaceAndDataset(newWorkspaceId, datasetId);
                                    if (gatewayId != null)
                                    {
                                        //update credentials
                                        await _powerBIService.UpdateGatewayDatasourcesCredentials(gatewayId, persona.SQLUser, persona.SQLPassword);
                                        Console.WriteLine("Updated connection details for gateway {0}", reportNameWithoutExtension);
                                    }
```

These are the individual methods:

```
 public async Task UpdateConnectionAsync(string workspaceId, string datasetId, string sqlUser, string sqlPwd)
    {
        var bearerToken = await GetBearerTokenAsync();
        var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(bearerToken, "Bearer");

        using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(_pbiApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
        {
            var dataSourcesResponse = await client.Datasets.GetDatasourcesInGroupAsync(workspaceId, datasetId);
            var sqlDataSources = dataSourcesResponse.Value?.Where(s => s.DatasourceType == "Sql")
                                                            .Where(s => !s.ConnectionString.Contains(_reportsSQLServer) || !s.ConnectionString.Contains(_reportsSQLServer));

            foreach (var sqlDataSource in sqlDataSources)
            {
                var updateDataSourceConnectionRequest = new UpdateDatasourceConnectionRequest();
                updateDataSourceConnectionRequest.ConnectionDetails = new DatasourceConnectionDetails(_reportsSQLServer, _reportsSQLDatabase);
                //updateDataSourceConnectionRequest.DatasourceSelector = new Datasource(datasourceId: sqlDataSource.DatasourceId);

                var datasourcesRequest = new UpdateDatasourcesRequest();
                datasourcesRequest.UpdateDetails = new List<UpdateDatasourceConnectionRequest>() { updateDataSourceConnectionRequest };

                var result = await client.Datasets.UpdateDatasourcesInGroupAsync(workspaceId, datasetId, datasourcesRequest);
                //await client.Gateways.UpdateDatasourceAsync()
            }
        }
    }

public async Task UpdateGatewayDatasourcesCredentials(string gatewayId, string sqlUser, string sqlPassword)
    {
        var bearerToken = await GetBearerTokenAsync();
        var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(bearerToken, "Bearer");

        using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(_pbiApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
        {
            var datasourcesResult = await client.Gateways.GetDatasourcesAsync(gatewayId);
            var sqlGatewayDatasources = datasourcesResult.Value?
                                            .Where(s => s.DatasourceType == "Sql")
                                            .Where(s => s.ConnectionDetails.Contains(_reportsSQLServer) && s.ConnectionDetails.Contains(_reportsSQLDatabase));

            foreach (var gatewayDatasource in sqlGatewayDatasources)
            {
                var updateDataSourceRequest = new UpdateDatasourceRequest();
                updateDataSourceRequest.CredentialDetails = new CredentialDetails();
                updateDataSourceRequest.CredentialDetails.CredentialType = "Basic";
                updateDataSourceRequest.CredentialDetails.Credentials = "{\"credentialData\":[{\"name\":\"username\", \"value\":\"" + sqlUser + "\"},{\"name\":\"password\", \"value\":\"" + sqlPassword + "\"}]}";
                updateDataSourceRequest.CredentialDetails.EncryptedConnection = "Encrypted";
                updateDataSourceRequest.CredentialDetails.EncryptionAlgorithm = "None";
                updateDataSourceRequest.CredentialDetails.PrivacyLevel = "None";

                var result = await client.Gateways.UpdateDatasourceAsync(gatewayId, gatewayDatasource.Id, updateDataSourceRequest);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I attempt to view the report there is no data being fetched from the database.
Interestingly I can login manually using the PowerBI portal using the same credentials. After the manual login the report is fetching data. 
If after the manual login I delete the workspace and then recreate and re-import the report programatically then the report will show data. This makes me think there is some caching involved after the manual logic which is persisted outside of the workspace.

Any suggestions on what is missing here?